how to use select2 in yii2 advanced,
When I use select2 in a yii2 form, an error like this always shows:

Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
You must install 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap' extension for Bootstrap 3.x version support. Dependency to 'yii2-bootstrap' has not been included with 'yii2-krajee-base'. To resolve, you must add 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap' to the 'require' section of your application's composer.json file and then run 'composer update'.
NOTE: This dependency change has been done since v2.0 of 'yii2-krajee-base' because only one of 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap' OR 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4' OR 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap5' extensions can be installed. The developer can thus choose and control which bootstrap extension library to install.

I have taken steps to resolve the error, but I still experience the same error

Error says You must install 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap' Did you try to do this?

What steps exactly did you try to take to resolve the error? You probably didn't set what version of bootstrap should be used. See https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#bs-info

@Mr.Kenneth nope, that part of error message is misleading. You need one of yii2-bootstrap, yii2-bootstrap4 or yii2-bootstrap5 packages. The package is looking for yii2-bootstrap by default but you can change it by setting the version. Yii2 advanced template has yii2-bootstrap5 among its dependencies already so you only need to set up BS version to 5.x.

You are using advanced template of yii2. You should add
'bsVersion' => '3.x', to you

common/config/main-local.php

file. You can change 3 to bootstrap version you are using.
